# Return value for updating data in the DAL when the value is not found

Tags: return-value, data-access-layer, sql-update

I know this is a nit picky question, but I'm curious what the majority of you guys are doing in this situation.

I have a DAL that updates a database record when it is called.  If the record in question does not exist, there are a few possibilities of how to return back to the BLL.

1) Return a boolean.  True means it was updated, false means it was not.
2) Return an exception indicating value to be updated was not found
3) Return the number of rows affected...however this doesn't make sense when the intent is a single row update
4) return a string saying "not found in database" (least favorite by far, but something that others have done around here).

I'm leaning between 1 or 2.  How do you guys feel about this?

Answer (score 0):

I would usually do 2) unless the 'not found' condition is not an exceptional case. If 'not found' is fairly common, I will usually do 1).

Comment: Sounds good.  2nd question, what type of exception would you use?

Answer (score 0):

Things to consider:

1. What is the behavior of other parts of your DAL?  It would be nice to have some consistency between how those different calls behave.
2. What is the language?  How it deals w/ exceptions would color my assessment of #2

W/o knowing either of these, I'd opt for #2: not only does it handle the particular situation described, but allows for addressing other reasons an update might fail w/o needing to add a new mechanism.

Comment: I agree with consistency.  Other parts of the dal that someone else wrote use strings and I hate it.  What I determine here will standardize it.  This is being written in c#.